# A function updating data and using the updated data again in one trial

Tags: python, django

I am working on a function that checks who submitted homework and calculate the penalty for those who didn't. Though it finely saves in db who did not submit homework, but a problem happens with the penalty. It is done in the same function (right after checking who handed in), but with old data. It does not get the updated data (+1 if not submitted). I think it is because the update and calculation are done all at once in one function, one trial. But I have no idea how to separate them or getting the updated data right.

I made a function outside the original function that only calculates the penalty and applied in the original function, intending to separate two functions (checking submission and calculating penalty) but it resulted in the same.

```
def group_update(request, group_id):
group = get_object_or_404(Group, id=group_id)
memberships = Membership.objects.filter(group=group)
members = [x.person for x in memberships]
```

## Checking submission

```
assignments = Assignment.objects.filter(done_checked=False, group=group, due_date__lte=datetime.now())
for assignment in assignments:
    submission = Done.objects.filter(assignment=assignment)
    submitters = [x.author for x in submission]
    assignment.done_checked = True
    assignment.save(update_fields=['done_checked'])
    for member in members:
        if member not in submitters:
            non_submit = memberships.get(person=member)
            non_submit.noshow_assign = non_submit.noshow_assign + 1
            non_submit.save()
```

## Calculating penalty

```
for membership in memberships:
    membership.penalty = membership.noshow_assign * group.penalty
    membership.save(update_fields=['penalty'])

return redirect(resolve_url('study:group_detail', group.id))
```

Checking submission is working well. (data was saved properly) So I thought calculating penalty would work too using the data updated with the fine function but it didn't. The data was right, but the thing is that the later function does not get the updated data T.T

Comment: can you try memberships.objects.filter(group=group).update(noshow_assign=F('noshow_assign')*group.penalty)

Comment: Thank you a lot! It successfully works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution `Memberships.objects.filter(group=group).update(noshow_assign=F('noshow_assign')*group.penalty)`